# How to set Spinner Default by its Value instead of Position?

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter, android-spinner

I have 1-50 records in the database. I am fetching those data using cursor and set those values to Spinner using Simple Cursor Adapter. Now what i need is i want to set one value say 39th value as default. But not by its position i want to set by its value.

I know how to set the spinner default by its position

```
   spinner.setSelection(39)
```

will set the spinner to that value.

But i didn't have any idea about setting the spinner default by its value(text) in the database.
I know the values in the database. For eg "books" is one of the value in the spinner. I need to set the spinner default as books.

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: It seems as if all you need is to fetch a value from the db. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @keyser No.. I fetched value from the database and set it to spinner using simple cursor adapter.. Now the thing is i need to set one value of the spinner as default by its value not by its position.. have i explained clearly

Comment: No, it still seems that you just have to get the value from db itself and set it with pinner.setSelection(somepositionvalue).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, i solved the problem by using following way, in which the position of the spinner can be get by its string

```
private int getPostiton(String locationid,Cursor cursor)
{
    int i;
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    for(i=0;i< cursor.getCount()-1;i++)
    {  

        String locationVal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RoadMoveDataBase.LT_LOCATION));  
        if(locationVal.equals(locationid))
        { 
            position = i+1;  
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            position = 0;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();  
    }
```

Calling the method

```
    Spinner location2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    int location2id = getPostiton(cursor.getString(3),cursor);
    location2.setSelection(location2id);
```

I hope it will help for some one..

Comment: Perhaps a bit leaner and more elegant version might look like this:

public class SpinnerHelper {
    public static int getPosition(String displayText, String fieldName, Cursor cursor) {
        int position = -1;
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(fieldName));
            if (text.equals(displayText)) {
                position = cursor.getPosition();
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return position;
    }
}

Answer (score 131):

If you are setting the spinner values by `ArrayList` or `Array` you can assign the spinner's selection by using the value's index.

```
String myString = "some value"; //the value you want the position for

ArrayAdapter myAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) mySpinner.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter

int spinnerPosition = myAdapter.getPosition(myString);

//set the default according to the value
spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

see the link [How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position)

Also, you can avoid the temporary integer variable "spinnerPosition " by directly using the method:

```
getPosition(String item)
```

Then the assigning code will be:

```
//set the default according to the value
spinner.setSelection(myAdapter.getPosition(myString));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. I know its possible using ArrayAdapter.. Is the same possible by Simple Cursor Adapter??

Comment: @Vino Yes, checkout the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11667045/293280

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 10):

Compare string with value from index

```
private void selectSpinnerValue(Spinner spinner, String myString)
     {
         int index = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++){
             if(spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals(myString)){
                 spinner.setSelection(i);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how i did it:

```
String[] listAges = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ages);

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listAges);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner_age.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.spinner_icon), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        spinner_age.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner_age.setSelection(0);
        spinner_age.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                if(position > 0){
                    // get spinner value
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Age..." + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    // show toast select gender
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "none" + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like this.

```
String cls=student.getStudentClass();
class_spinner.setSelection(classArray.indexOf(cls),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list you use for the spinner is an object then you can find its position like this

```
private int selectSpinnerValue( List<Object> ListSpinner,String myString) 
{
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ListSpinner.size(); i++){
      if(ListSpinner.get(i).getValueEquals().equals(myString)){
          index=i;
          break;
      }
    }
    return index;
}
```

using:

```
 int index=selectSpinnerValue(ListOfSpinner,StringEquals);
    spinner.setSelection(index,true);
```