# Android: Setting spinner with values from DB - but base array is in String

Tags: android

My preset values for the spinner comes from a String Array.

```
<string-array name="currencyArray">
    <item>INR</item>
    <item>USD</item>
    <item>EUR</item>
</string-array>
```

I am able to display this and save this fine.
I am adding some values in a SQLite DB on "Add".
 On update, i want to fetch the values and display on screen. One of them is the spinner.

I tried this code

```
String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Currency");
System.out.println(myString);
ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) currencySpin.getAdapter();
int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);
//set the default according to value
currencySpin.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

The sysout (line 2) actually displays the correct value from the DB. But the spinner still displays the initial value and not the DB value.
What am i missing here?

I am using this code to populate and read the spinner in an empty screen

```
// reading the spinner
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,
    R.array.currencyArray, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
currencySpin.setAdapter(adapter);

currencySpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Updated code

```
            String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Currency");
        System.out.println(myString);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
        .createFromResource(this, R.array.currencyArray,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(myString);
        System.out.println(spinnerPosition);

        //set the default according to value
        currencySpin.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

The spinnerPosition is coming as the correct number (changes from 0 to 2 as per my data), but the currencySpin (my spinner) does not display it correctly. What am i missing??

Comment: did you check the value of `myAdap.getPosition(myString)` in line 4?

Comment: yes, its always 1. Am not sure why that is.

Comment: instead of passing String value of spinner in extra y dont you pass the selected index in extras so that you can directly set it.

Comment: try using new ArrayAdapter so it rebinds the string everytime it is updated.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2390140/1438915 its similar what you wnat.

Comment: am getting it from the DB (a SQLite). this line - String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Currency"); , fetches the values from the DB - either as INR, USD or EUR. I am not storing the index during the ADD earlier anyways.

Comment: @Siddhesh - yes, i did check that post and my code is a copy paste of that. It still didnt work and i was looking for help as to why that is so.

Comment: make an arraylist of array which you ar e suppling to adapter and find arraylist.indexOf(myString); and then set the returened index for selection of spinner

Comment: I have updated my code in the question. Now the spinnerPosition is picking up the right number - but the spinner still shows the default value. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it using this updated Code. This is for anyone else who is looking for this solution

```
                // reading the spinner
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
                    .createFromResource(this, R.array.currencyArray,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            currencySpin.setAdapter(adapter);

            currencySpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            spinnerPosition = 0;
            String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("Currency");
            spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(myString);
            currencySpin.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```