# How to search in android spinner dropdown

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a spinner dropdown in android and it is populated with list of names as text and ID as value. Now the issue is I have a textbox where user inputs string and on button click item with the name like textbox string should get automatically selected. I searched on google , but couldn't find anything useful. I used

```
 drpMaterial.setSelection(p);
```

but it works on index, I was looking for something which will work on  text not the value in spinnner dropdown.

My code for populating spinner dropdown:

```
 Itm=new CItem( "-1", "Select Material" );
                lstItm.add(Itm);
                for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {

                    jsonmain = j.getJSONObject(i);

                    Itm=new CItem(jsonmain.getString("ID"),jsonmain.getString("Text"));
                    lstItm.add(Itm);


                }
 if(lstItm.size()>0) {
             ArrayAdapter<CItem> adapterProj = new ArrayAdapter<CItem>(myactivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstItm);

             drpProj.setAdapter(adapterProj);
         }
```

Comment: Searchable Spinner (search with text)  check this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74606327/12750160

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by adding this library

Add this to your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
}
```

You can now add in your layout.xml file these lines:

```
<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Add this in your activity and you are good to go!

```
searchableSpinner.setTitle("Select Item");
searchableSpinner.setPositiveButton("OK");
```

Check out the link below for more information

https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner

Comment: Thankyou very much, you saved my day. This is really good and simple solution.

Comment: This Dependency not working now. Error in 'compile' and 'xml' code

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select by value from resource, try to use this code.

```
 String compareValue= "some value";
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.select_state, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 MySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

 if (!compareValue.equals(null)) 
 {
     int spinnerPostion = adapter.getPosition(compareValue);
     MySpinner.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
     spinnerPostion = 0;
 }
```

for a custom adapter, for example `CursorAdapter`, you will have to write (override) the code for getPosition()

source: [How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position)

Comment: It will only work when item is supplied to getpostion method() with both value and text but I want to search dropdown only by text without considering its value part.@Anil actually I am populating dropdown by arraylist with both text and value parts.