# Second spinner's position set to default when selection of first changes

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have two spinners, both have 2 items in them. when i change my selection in spinner one i want to change seconds selection to default.
how can i achieve that?
here is my code that i have tried

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    x = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
    y = s2.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (x){
        case(0):
            y=0;
            switch (y){
                case(0):b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    c1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    c2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case(1):
                    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    c1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    c2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case(1):
            s2.setSelection(0);
            switch (y){
                case(0):b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    c1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    c2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case(1):
                    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    c2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    c1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: 2nd spinner value depends on the first spinner selection value?

Comment: yes if value of spinner 1 changes spinner 2 should set to dafault value i.e. 0

Comment: Check my answer and when first item select then set 2nd spinner default value using this spinnerObject.setSelection(position) // Default position may be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spinnerObject.setSelection(DEFAULT_INDEX) to set the second spinner when you want to change it back to it's default.

```
spinnerObject.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: It is givinng Cannot Resolve Symbol DEFAULT_INDEX error

Comment: DEFAULT_INDEX is a placeholder, you should put your default index in there.

Comment: It can be a position. Can be int number.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> secondspinnerAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> firstspinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, firstspinnervalue);

first_spinner.setAdapter(firstspinnerAdapter);      
firstspinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
firstspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {                       
                        // set data in arraylist.
                      secondspinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( mainActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  arraylistvalue);
                      second_spinner.setAdapter(secondspinnerAdapter);
                      second_spinner.setSelection(arg2, false);
                      secondspinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                      (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

See this link : [How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position)