# Spinner- How to convert from getSelectedItem().toString() from a spinner, back to a spinner?

Tags: android, string, android-spinner

I have this spinner to and i want to get the selected item to a string and i do this:

```
Spinner to;
String string = to.getSelectedItem().toString;
```

My question is how to convert "string" back to spinner widget?

Comment: What does it mean that "how to convert "string" back to spinner widget"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is better:**

[How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position)

**This will also work:** (my answer)
You create a Spinner with an Array(List). If you want to set the Spinner to the string you got from the Spinner itself, something like this would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    if (array.get(i).equals(string) {
        spinner.setSelection(i)
    }
}
```