# not working spinner onItemSelectedListner after closing dialog

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner above a list vivew.
i select item from spinner, Listview is updated and My app works correctly.
but When a layer is selected from listView (with description and Advertise) open a dialog
when i click on Advertise in  dialog, close dialog
but not working OnItemSelectedListenet
By returning to the previous page and Reentering the page, the spinner works

```
OnItemSelectedListener selectedListener1 = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
      //my code     
    }

    @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
    };

    OnItemSelectedListener selectedListener2 = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
            //my code
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner1 = new AdapterSpinner(G.context, R.layout.spinner_item, items1);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapterSpinner1);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(selectedListener1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner2 = new AdapterSpinner(G.context, R.layout.spinner_item, items2);
    sp2.setAdapter(adapterSpinner2);
    sp2.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sp2.setSelection(3);
        }
    });
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(selectedListener2);
}
```

Comment: can you post your full code??

Comment: go through these link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position?rq=1
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event?rq=1
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinner?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating different selected listener, Implement activity with onItemSelectedListener  It will provide you method

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
if(view==sp1){//do something}
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

and in you oncreate

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```