# Display Drop down Items using custom Class which extends Dialog Class in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am displaying a drop down by using custom class which extends Dialog class. I have a large number of values so when the drop down opens by default focus is set on the last item. Can anybody suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Check out Answers in this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390102/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position

Comment: This question is using spinner for displaying drop down values. I am using dialog class for displaying drop down values.